# how do i return js with %form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I force js? changing my form action to: /portal/checkout.js renders the code in plain text.. What am I missing?

ruby 1.9.3p194  -  Rails 3.1.3

```
%form#online_bill_pay{:action => "/portal/checkout", :method => "post", :remote => true}
  ...
  = submit_tag "", id: 'pay_amount', class: 'btn-success btn shadowed', remote: true
```

returns:

```
Missing template portals/checkout, application/checkout with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/home/pete/Projects/umbie/app/views" * "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@umbie/gems/jasminerice-0.0.8/app/views" * "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@umbie/gems/mailboxer-0.5.4/app/views" * "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@umbie/gems/bootstrap_kaminari-0.0.5/app/views" * "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@umbie/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views" * "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@umbie/gems/devise-1.5.0/app/views" * "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@umbie/gems/doorkeeper-1.0.0/app/views"
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using rails' `form_for` ?

Comment: im not using a model..

Comment: You don't need a model to use `form_for`.

Comment: Try changing your action to `/portal/checkout.js` It is the format of the request that determines what view is shown.

Comment: If you're using 3.1.3 you should probably upgrade immediately to a newer, safer version of 3.1.x. There are a [large number of vulnerabilities in 3.1.3](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-12043/product_id-22568/version_id-129541/year-2012/Rubyonrails-Ruby-On-Rails-3.1.3.html).

Comment: @DickieBoy read the question... When I do that, it returns plain text.

Comment: @tadman I am aware. We are in the middle of upgrading...

Comment: Good to know. As a note a service like [GemCanary](http://gemcanary.com/) provides automatic alerts for this sort of thing so you won't get caught out.

Comment: @DickieBoy I am unaware of how to use form_for without a model. link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem... My HAML syntax was compiling to 'remote true' instead of 'data remote true' This solved it:

```
= form_tag(checkout_portal_path(format: :js), :method => :post, remote: true) do
```